# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified, Connector 'oracle', Method -Connect-

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a production lotus-script agent working which connects to oracle. After upgrade to(windows 2008 box,oracle 11g,lotus domino 9.0.1)the agent is  not working.getting the error "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified,  Connector 'oracle',  Method -xxxx".
I followed the below approach which works,
1. I Created a sample LC connection lotus script agent works fine when I ran manually from the client.
2.form admin console forced the agent to RUN on server using command << tell amgr run "database path" 'agent name' >>  also connecting to oracle through the tnsnames.ora file.

but I am getting error when scheduled to run the agent by server. anybody have any idea why its failing?? or anybody come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

bit weird,but after restart the domino server the same agent started working fine.